# wsgi_mod installation in windows 10

Tags: python-3.x, mod-wsgi

I want to install WSGI for python web application on windows-10. But when I run **pip install mod_wsgi** command i get error.

*error: command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\link.exe' failed with exit status 1120*
Anybody can resolve this problem?

Comment: That message is not the actual error message. Need to see the errors before that which indicate the real problem. Also need to know what Python version you are using, what Apache version and where you go it from, and where Apache is installed.

Answer (score 1):

Current understanding is that 32 bit builds are broken. That or you are mixing 32 bit and 64 bit versions of Python, Apache or the Windows compilers. They must be all 32 bit or all 64 bit.

Comment: Uninstall the 32 bit versions and install only 64 bit builds