# Encountering exit status 1120 when trying to install mod_wsgi using pip

Tags: python, apache, pip, mod-wsgi

so I'm new to python and trying to set up an Apache server to use with django. I already set up django and set the Apache directory and installed C++ version 14.0, but now I'm encountering the following error when trying to install mod_wsgi:

error: command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\bin\HostX86\x86\link.exe' failed with exit status 1120

I can't find anything useful on how to fix this error and install mod_wsgi, so any help would be appreciated. I am using python 3.7.0 and using Windows 10. I will edit this post with more info about my setup if needed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmod-wsgi%5D+%5Bpip%5D+failed+with+exit+status+1120

Comment: Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48617123/7976758)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46630144/7976758

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue because my Apache installation on Windows was 32Bit. Everything else was 64Bit

I installed XAMPP and it worked in the end.